# Issue with form action on masterpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, master-pages

I have a masterpage for my website.  On that masterpage there is a form tag.  This tag encapsulates every thing that is on that page.  The problem I'm having is I have a retailer locator on that page and there is an input box that I'm wanting to use to pass in a variable to the retailer locator that is on a different page.  I tested out the input box on a page outside of the masterpage and the method I was using to pass in the variable was working.  When I load it onto the masterpage it no longer works.  Instead of going to the page I want, it takes me back to the homepage.  Below is the code that I'm using.  I'm not sure if it's because I have to form tags on the page, but I'm not sure how I can resolve this issue.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
  <script>
   $_POST['address'];

   </script>
   </head>

   <form  runat="server">
   <div class="page">
    <div class="header">
    <br />

    <div id="topinformation" class="topinfo">
    <div> 
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
         ImageUrl="~/Images/Logo New.png" Height="70px" Width="182px" 
        CssClass="logo" PostBackUrl="~/Default.aspx"/>


    <form action="TestLocator2.aspx?address=">
     <input type="text" value="FIND A RETAILER" 
onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='FIND A RETAILER';" 
onfocus="if(this.value=='FIND A RETAILER')this.value='';" name="address"   /><input type="hidden" />
</form>
<div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
 </form>
</body>
 </html>
   </div>
```

Comment: Well, you need begin your `<body>` tag right after you close your `<head>` tag and you need to close the `<form  runat="server">` form somewhere. Not sure what `$_POST['address'];` is doing in a `<script>` tag, too (if ASP.net is taking care of that, then sorry, but it looks like PHP to me). As for the `<input>` tag thick, it seems to be working, even when I paste all of what should be in the `<body>` tag into a `<body>` tag. Can you make a fiddle or something of the like?

Comment: You copied the exact code?  When I try and do this, it takes me back to the home page.  I think it's probably because I have the image button that takes me back to the home page and when I press the enter it's thinking I'm clicking on that button instead of the address bar.  It let you run this successfully with having the two form controls in there?  I'm still not having any luck.

Comment: Actually, I don't have ASP.net, so I can't run this. I only tested `<input type="text" value="FIND A RETAILER" 
onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='FIND A RETAILER';" 
onfocus="if(this.value=='FIND A RETAILER')this.value='';" name="address"   />`.

Comment: Ok so that's probably the issue then.  It works when I have it in my project without the MasterPage, but when I add the code into the MasterPage that's when I'm encountering the error.